# Ratio of users not returning email addresses via the facebook api

Tags: php, facebook, email, facebook-graph-api, captiveportal

We are running into some issues with the facebook graph API and we are looking to confirm our findings.

We utilise Facebook login to allow users to login to our app seamlessly, unfortunately on a high number of ocassions we are seeing facebook not returning any email address or a xxx@facebook.com address.

We understand the reasoning behind this and appreciate we have a slight different business case than other integrators and completely agree on facebooks decision to not allow emails to be available under certain circumstances.

Unfortunately our ratio of bad emails is so high that is creating a significant impact. We rely on these emails to communicate with our audience (captive portal) and facebook email addresses are bad for this purpose.

We are wondering if **the ~60% no email returned from facebook** is the norm.

Are you running a large site with facebook login enabled? What are the metrics you guys are seeing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the facebook.com address is still a thing? anyway, you only get an email if the user logged in with an email, and if the email is approved by facebook. why not just present an email input field on authorization if the email does not exist?

Comment: AFAIK the foo@facebook.com email addresses are only forwarded to the main contact email the user has set these days (they do not show up as messages on Facebook any more.) And I am not sure if they actually go anywhere, if the user doesn’t have an email address on file with Facebook. I’d recommend to filter out all foo@facebook.com addresses, and ask the user to provide an email address manually. (Of course, if you need it to be verified, that’d be your own responsibility as well then.)